# How to search GitHub issues for the ones you're watching?

Tags: github, github-issues, github-search

How can we search/filter GitHub issues for the ones you've previously marked as 'watching'?

I can't spot any way to do it via the GUI, but perhaps there's some search parameter?

I took a guess and tried `watching:true` and [`currentUser()`](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Core-questions/how-to-find-all-issues-i-am-watching/qaq-p/2332), but neither seemed to work

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not get a web-based search filter for "watched": the [Advanced search](https://github.com/search/advanced) does not include anything related to "watched/watching".

Even the GitHub API does not include anything regarding watching at the issue level.
There are only API calls for [listing watchers at the repository level](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity#watching).

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Do you know if there's any work around, hacky or otherwise? Currently I know I'm watching one issue in [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues) but currently I've narrowed it down to 1 out of a possible 4000..

Comment: @stevec No, but I didn't need such a workaround, because the https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions page would list all the watched issues for me.

Comment: It definitely narrows it down (to a few hundred rather than a few thousand). Other than creating a custom web scraper to iterate through those pages, do you know if there's a way to search 'watching' ?

Comment: @stevec the "watching" tab is for repositories. You might want to search the "Subscriptions" tab, which is for issues. For that, check out the Notification API: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity#notifications

Answer (score 3):

You can see all your subscriptions at https://github.com/notifications/subscriptions. You can filter by reason and repository and sort by *Most recently subscribed* or *Least recently subscribed*.

[image: Screenshot of subscriptions overview]

Available subscription-reason filters

- *Any reason* - Show all subscriptions
- *Assign* - You were assigned to the Issue/PR.
- *Author* - You created the thread.
- *Comment* - You commented on the thread.
- *Manual* - You subscribed to the thread (via an Issue or Pull Request).
- *Mention* - You were specifically @mentioned in the content.
- *Review Requested* - You were requested for review.
- *State Change* - You changed the thread state (for example, closing an Issue or merging a Pull Request).
- *Team Mention* - You were on a team that was mentioned.